# Não estou conseguindo autenticar usando middleware auth do laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Eu consigo fazer autenticação normal quando não coloco as rotas dentro de um grupo.

Quando eu coloco as rotas que só podem ser acessadas com login, a página não redireciona para a área administrativa.

Quando verifico o que o método `Attempt` do `Auth` está retornando, ele retorna `true` e até consigo visualizar os dados do usuário usando o método `dd()`, porem não me redireciona para a página certa.

```
//Esse é meu arquivo Route
Route::get('/', 'Login\LoginController@index')->name('login');
Route::post('/login/entrar', 'Login\LoginController@entrar')->name('login.entrar');
Route::get('/login/sair','Login\LoginController@sair')->name('login.sair');


Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
 Route::get('/admin/exibir', 'Home\HomeController@index')->name('admin.exibir');
 Route::get('/admin/buscar', 'Home\HomeController@buscar')->name('admin.buscar'); 
});
```

---

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Login;

use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use App\User; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class LoginController extends Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function entrar(Request $request)
    {   
        $dados = $request->All();
        if(Auth::attempt(['name'=>$dados['user'],'password'=>$dados['password']]))
        {
            return redirect()->route('admin.exibir');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }   
    }
    public function sair()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Você parece que mudou e construiu outra autentificação por isso pode colocar os Controller

Comment: Posso sim, estranho pq eu segui o mesmo código que eu fiz uma vez e tinha funcionado, achei que era diferença de versão, mas não é.

Comment: No seu controller deveria ser email ou você mudou no Model?

Comment: Eu mudei na model para name

Comment: Eu não entendi bem, o que acontece ele não redireciona para a tela?

Comment: Não, ele entra no metodo de autenticação na controller e faz a autenticação, mas na hora de redirecionar a página para a página administrativa ele volta pra tela de login.

Comment: Então ele não está autenticando ... e ai é investigação para saber o motivo, tem que postar o model User e tem que ver se realmente ele criou a sessão para você, que acredito que não.

Comment: Como eu vejo se a session foi criada?

Comment: Como ver a session? investigar na área que está sendo gerado que é na pasta `storage/framework/sessions` ... se não estiver alterado isso também